# Is this answer correct?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question I was checking out is: ***Differentiate each function with respect to x using Product Rule***

$y = (5x^3 + 2)(-6x^4 - 6x^3)$

1. $\frac {dy}{dx} = -210x^6 - 180x^5 - 48x^3 - 36x^2$
2. $\frac {dy}{dx} = -180x^6 - 150x^5 - 48x^3 - 36x^2$

Is answer 1. or 2. correct?

I have worked out 2. to be what I think is correct.

Comment: You could check your work by multiplying out $y$ and taking the derivative of the polynomial without the product rule.  Or maybe just check the highest order term in your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the highest degree term which is $-30x^{7}$ and its derivative is $-210x^{6}$ so the answer cannot be 2

Comment: See how he tricked you into giving him the answer?  He didn't really work out that 2 was the answer, he just picked it at random.

Comment: Thanks, found my mistake. When expanding the brackets I somehow thought 6 x 15 = 60 instead of 90, hence being out by 30 in first two terms.